# Visual Studio 2015 Clang Debugging

Tags: c, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, clang

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with the clang compiler (Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2015 - Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v140_clang_c2)) to compile a simple program as shown below:

```
struct IUnknown; // Only included for clang compiler error with Update 3

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x = 5;
    char temp[] = "Test";
    x += 10;
    printf("Hello world");

    return 0;
}
```

When setting a breakpoint at the beginning of the program and stepping through, I'm not able to hover over x and see the value like I would expect as part of the debugging in the IDE. Additionally, typing the variable "temp" into the memory window yields "unable to evaluate expression". If I leave the code the same and change the compiler to MSVC (Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2015 (v140)) and I step through the debugger I am able to hover and see the values and use the variable "temp" in the memory window. Is this something to do with Clang with Visual Studio IDE? Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Can you share a screen shot about the result in your side? Do you use the "step Into" after the breakpoint was hit? I could view the X variable or in debug watch window and the temp(0x00D2F8CC) shows normally in memory window, could you reset your VS settings? and then debug it again. I just use the default settings in my VS2015.

Comment: How about the result? fowlball1010.